discord js v14 make buttons interaction execute in an other file
I've been looking to make button files on a /commands bot, but I don't have any idea on how to do it
I know it should be possible because in the discord documentation they tell we can do this in the interactionCreate.js file
} else if (interaction.isButton()) {
    // respond to the button
}

But I have no idea on how to :

handle this in the command file where we create the button (I suppose I just have to create the button and the customId will determine which file it will execute)
manage this is the interactionCreate.js file
Get the files (if different from commands / events / context menus)

Can someone explain me how it works ?

Okay so I managed to make it work.
Here is the process :
First of all, create a new buttons Collection like the commands one, but with a slight modification in the if
client.buttons = new Collection();
const buttonsFoldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'buttons');
const buttonFolders = fs.readdirSync(buttonsFoldersPath);

for (const folder of buttonFolders) {
    const buttonsPath = path.join(buttonsFoldersPath, folder);
    const buttonsFiles = fs.readdirSync(buttonsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of buttonsFiles) {
        const filePath = path.join(buttonsPath, file);
        const button = require(filePath);
        if ('execute' in button) {
            client.buttons.set(path.parse(file).name, button);
        } else {
            console.log(`[WARNING] The button at ${filePath} is missing a required "execute" property.`);
        }
    }
}

Now, we need to handle the button click interaction in the interactionCreate.js file
Again, it is just a slight modification of the command interaction handler
 else if (interaction.isButton()) {
    const button = interaction.client.buttons.get(interaction.customId);

    if (!button) {
        console.error(`No button matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`);
    }

    try {
        await button.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error executing ${interaction.customId}`);
        console.error(error);
    }

}

And we finally have to create a file at src/buttons/someFolder/file.js
module.exports = {
    async execute(interaction) {
        console.log("Button clicked!");
    }
};

